# gwt 2.8 beta1 - trying to invoke a java method from javascript using jsinterop

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin, gwt-2.8

I am trying to invoke a gwt method from javascript using latest JsInterop -
below is the head part of my html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--                                                               -->
<!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
<!--                                                               -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css">

<!--                                           -->
<!-- Any title is fine                         -->
<!--                                           -->
<title>Web Application Starter Project</title>

<!--                                           -->
<!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
<!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
<!-- be added before this line.                -->
<!--                                           -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"    src="Home/Home.nocache.js"></script>

</head>
```

below is the body part of my html

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script >
function myFunction(){
    alert("something to say");
    var foo = new host.Employee();
    foo.hello("Gautam");
}
</script>

<!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript  enabled -->

<h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>

<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please enter your name:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="nameFieldContainer"></td>
    <td id="sendButtonContainer"></td>
    <td id="someButton"><input type="button" value="SomeValue"  onclick=myFunction()/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Here is the java class

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;

import jsinterop.annotations.JsMethod;
import jsinterop.annotations.JsType;

@JsType(namespace = "host" , name = "Employee" )
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private String name ;
private int age ;
private long salary ;

@JsMethod(name = "hello")
public String sayHello(String name){
    String last = "Hello " + name ;  
    Window.alert(last);
    return last ;
}
}
```

In the browser the body onload=myFunction() gets called and the first alert is shown always.

But clicking the button someValue shows the first alert from myFunction but the expected host.Employee() always shows a undefined

```
Home.html:47 Uncaught ReferenceError: host is not defined
```

Could you point me to what's wrong here ?

I am building with gwt-maven-plugin for 2.8.0-beta1.

Update - here is my pom content
    
    4.0.0

```
  <parent>
    <artifactId>bi-parent-client</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.pa.bi</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.pa.bi</groupId>
  <artifactId>bi-gwt-host</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven Archetype for GWT</name>
<properties>
<!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
<gwtVersion>2.8.0-beta1</gwtVersion>

<!-- GWT needs at least java 1.7 -->
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<!-- Output classes directly into the webapp, so that IDEs and "mvn process- classes" update them in DevMode -->
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

<plugins>

  <!-- Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0-beta1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>test</goal>
          <goal>generateAsync</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
      gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
    <configuration>
      <runTarget>Home.html</runTarget>
      <modules>
        <module>com.pa.bi.gwt.host.Home</module>
      </modules>
      <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I added the

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled"
    value="true" />
```

to my Home.gwt.xml module file. But still no luck

Update -

removed jsInterOpMode flag and added

```
<generateJsInteropExports>true</generateJsInteropExports>
```

and my maven gwt:run throws a weird error -

```
[ERROR] Unable to find 'JS_RC.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

It would typically mean I need to inherit a module and I looked for a such a module in gwt project on github but so far no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in GWT 2.8.0-beta1 when using `-generateJsInteropExports` with SDM; it's been fixed but not yet released: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9223

Try using GWT 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Will try it out now. Also none of the samples available actually show a plain example of doing this. I am not keen on using vaadin stuff and libraries that wrap all the internals.

Comment: where can I get the snapshots ? I don't think they are on maven central

Comment: Strictly speaking, Central only hosts releases. GWT snapshots are on Sonatype OSSRH (sometimes thought of as "central snapshots"), but on a special repository: `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/`

Comment: I added the said repo to my local jfrog artifactory and I can see the jars there through browse. But due to some reason my eclipse and .m2 folder do not receive it. a bit strange for me

Comment: I forgot to add the new repo configured in artifactory to the virtual repo exposed i.e. remote repos.. and now jsinterop works like a charm :)